# SharpDX draw multiple primitives at the same time

Tags: c#, wpf, directx, sharpdx

I am trying to create a high level API with sharpdx. It has to be able to draw, but I am stuck on how to make it work with multiple Draw calls at the same time.

This is how I call the class

```
DirectXFinalD d33d = new DirectXFinalD();
```

Here I create a new object of the type viereck(rectangle)

```
Viereck viereck = new Viereck(0, 0, 0.2, 0.1, myBrush, myBrush, 1, false);
```

Here I pass the object to the class

```
d33d.DrawDirectX(viereck);
```

And it already works, but the problem is, I want it to be able that you can pass more objects at any given time, and let them be drawn.
I already tried to always update the vertexbuffer and always += the vertices, but the problem is that different shapes need different topologies. Here is the class:

```
namespace DrawHost
{

public class DirectXFinalD : DrawHost.DirectXBaseD<D3D11>, IDrawable
{

 ;
    public DirectXFinalD(IDrawable objectToDraw = null, DataStream stream = null)
    {
        this.objectToDraw = objectToDraw;
        if (stream == null)
        stream = new DataStream(32 * 612500, true, true); 
        else
        this.stream = stream;
    }

    protected override void Attach()
    {
        #region Shader
        if (Renderer == null)
            return;
        device = Renderer.Device;
        context = device.ImmediateContext;

        // Compile Vertex and Pixel shaders
        vertexShaderByteCode = ShaderBytecode.CompileFromFile("MiniTri.fx", "VS", "vs_4_0", ShaderFlags.None, EffectFlags.None);
        vertexShader = new VertexShader(device, vertexShaderByteCode);
        pixelShaderByteCode = ShaderBytecode.CompileFromFile("MiniTri.fx", "PS", "ps_4_0", ShaderFlags.None, EffectFlags.None);
        pixelShader = new PixelShader(device, pixelShaderByteCode);

        // Layout from VertexShader input signature
        layout = new InputLayout(device, ShaderSignature.GetInputSignature(vertexShaderByteCode), new[] {
            new InputElement("POSITION",0,Format.R32G32B32A32_Float,0,0),
            new InputElement("COLOR",0,Format.R32G32B32A32_Float,16,0)
        });
        #endregion
        if (objectToDraw == null) { }
        else
        {
            float r = 0;
            float g = 0;
            float b = 0;
            switch (objectToDraw.ToString())
            {   
                #region Dreieck
                case "Dreieck":
                    Dreieck dreieck = (Dreieck)objectToDraw;
                    topology = PrimitiveTopology.TriangleStrip;
                    ConvertColor(ref r, ref g, ref b, ((System.Windows.Media.SolidColorBrush)dreieck.Color).Color);

                    streamList.Add(new Vector4((Convert.ToSingle(dreieck.X)), (Convert.ToSingle(dreieck.Y) / 10), 0f, 1.0f)); streamList.Add(new Vector4(r, g, b, 1.0f));
                    streamList.Add(new Vector4(((Convert.ToSingle(dreieck.X) + Convert.ToSingle(dreieck.Width))), -(Convert.ToSingle(dreieck.Y)), 0f, 1.0f)); streamList.Add(new Vector4(r, g, b, 1.0f));
                    streamList.Add(new Vector4(-(Convert.ToSingle(dreieck.X)), -((Convert.ToSingle(dreieck.Y) + Convert.ToSingle(dreieck.Height) )), 0f, 1.0f)); streamList.Add(new Vector4(r, g, b, 1.0f));

                    break;
                #endregion

                #region Viereck
                case "Viereck":
                    Viereck viereck = (Viereck)objectToDraw;
                    topology = PrimitiveTopology.TriangleStrip;
                    ConvertColor(ref r, ref g, ref b, ((System.Windows.Media.SolidColorBrush)viereck.Color).Color);

                    streamList.Add(new Vector4((Convert.ToSingle(viereck.X)), (Convert.ToSingle(viereck.Y)), 0f, 1.0f)); streamList.Add(new Vector4(r, g, b, 1.0f));// ok
                    streamList.Add(new Vector4(((Convert.ToSingle(viereck.X))), (Convert.ToSingle(viereck.Y) + Convert.ToSingle(viereck.Height)), 0f, 1.0f)); streamList.Add(new Vector4(r, g, b, 1.0f));// ok
                    streamList.Add(new Vector4((Convert.ToSingle(viereck.X) + Convert.ToSingle(viereck.Width)), (Convert.ToSingle(viereck.Y) ), 0f, 1.0f)); streamList.Add(new Vector4(r, g, b, 1.0f));// ok
                    streamList.Add(new Vector4((Convert.ToSingle(viereck.X) + Convert.ToSingle(viereck.Width)), ((Convert.ToSingle(viereck.Y) + Convert.ToSingle(viereck.Height))), 0f, 1.0f)); streamList.Add(new Vector4(r, g, b, 1.0f));// ok

                    break;
                #endregion

                #region Kreis
                case "Kreis":
                    topology = PrimitiveTopology.Undefined;
                    Kreis kreis = (Kreis)objectToDraw;
                    ConvertColor(ref r, ref g, ref b, ((System.Windows.Media.SolidColorBrush)kreis.Color).Color);
                    for (float j = 0; j <= 360; j++)
                    {
                        for (double i = 0; i <= 360; i++) //254
                    { 
                            double rad = i * (Math.PI / 180);
                            float x = (float)Math.Cos(rad) * ((float)kreis.Width / 2);
                            float y = (float)Math.Sin(rad) * ((float)kreis.Height / 2);
                        streamList.Add(new Vector4(x , y, 0f, 1.0f)); streamList.Add(new Vector4(r, g, b, 1.0f));


                        }
                    }

                    break;
                    #endregion

            };

            foreach (Vector4 a in streamList)
            {
                stream.WriteRange(new[] { a });
            }
            stream.Position = 0;
            streamGV streamGV = new streamGV(stream);
            //streamGV.GetList(streamList);
            //streamList = null;
            GC.Collect();
        }
        vertices = new Buffer(device, stream, new BufferDescription()
        {
            BindFlags = BindFlags.VertexBuffer,
            CpuAccessFlags = CpuAccessFlags.None,
            OptionFlags = ResourceOptionFlags.None,
            SizeInBytes = (int)stream.Length,
            Usage = ResourceUsage.Default,
            StructureByteStride = 0,
        });

        stream.Dispose();


        // Prepare All the stages
        context.InputAssembler.InputLayout = (layout);
        context.InputAssembler.PrimitiveTopology = topology;
        context.InputAssembler.SetVertexBuffers(0, new VertexBufferBinding(vertices, 32, 0));
        context.VertexShader.Set(vertexShader);
        context.PixelShader.Set(pixelShader);

    }



    public override void RenderScene(DrawEventArgs args)
    {
        Renderer.Device.ImmediateContext.ClearRenderTargetView(Renderer.RenderTargetView, new Color4(0.6f, 0, 0, 0));
        Renderer.Device.ImmediateContext.Draw((int)stream.Length, 0);

        return;
    }

    public override void Case(DXElement dxviewer)
    {
        dxviewer11 = dxviewer;

}

    public override void DrawDirectX(IDrawable objectToDraw)
    {
        this.objectToDraw = objectToDraw;
        //dxviewer11.Renderer = new Scene_11();
        //Renderer = new D3D11();
        stream =  new DataStream(32 * 612500, true, true);
        streamGV strean = new streamGV();
        dxviewer11.Renderer = new DirectXFinalD(objectToDraw, stream) { Renderer = new D3D11() };



    }

    private void ConvertColor(ref float r, ref float g, ref float b, System.Windows.Media.Color color)
    {
        r = (float)(color.R * 255);
        g = (float)(color.G * 255);
        b = (float)(color.B * 255);
    }



}
```

How can I make it possible to draw all of them at the same time? I am using sharpdx as my renderform. One problem is that I always have to change the topology, for example triangle needs `trianglelist`but for the circle I use `Linestrip`. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

As I can see you're calling the Attach ones. In this attach method you're only creating 1 vertex buffer, with a mesh depending on `objectToDraw`.

You should decouple you shader compilation code and your vertexbuffer setup.

You could create a class that will manage the vertexbuffer and 'knows' how to draw the mesh.

For example:   (PSEUDO)

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct Vertex
{
    public const int Stride = 16 + 16;

    public Vector4 Pos;
    public Color4 Color;
}

public class Mesh
{
    private Vertex[] _vertices;
    private int[] _indices;

    private SharpDX.Direct3D11.Buffer _indexBuffer;
    private SharpDX.Direct3D11.Buffer _vertexBuffer;
    private VertexBufferBinding _vertexBufferBinding;

    public Mesh(Vertex[] vertices, int[] indices)
    {
        // save the vertices in a field
        _vertices = value;

        var vbd = new BufferDescription(
            SharpDX.Utilities.SizeOf<Vertex>() * _vertices.Length,
            ResourceUsage.Immutable,
            BindFlags.VertexBuffer,
            CpuAccessFlags.None,
            ResourceOptionFlags.None,
            0);

        // setup the vertex buffer
        _vertexBuffer = SharpDX.Direct3D11.Buffer.Create<Vertex>(DX11.Device, _vertices, vbd);

        // create the binding
        _vertexBufferBinding = new VertexBufferBinding(_vertexBuffer, Vertex.Stride, 0);


        _indices = value;

        var ibd = new BufferDescription(
               sizeof(int) * _indices.Length,
               ResourceUsage.Immutable,
               BindFlags.IndexBuffer,
               CpuAccessFlags.None,
               ResourceOptionFlags.None,
               0);

        // setup the index buffer
        _indexBuffer = SharpDX.Direct3D11.Buffer.Create<int>(DX11.Device, _indices, ibd);
    }

    // the SelectBuffers will select the right vertex buffer.
    // this could be combined with the Draw method, but I rather not
    // You should call this ones even when you draw multiple the same mesh.
    public void SelectBuffers()
    {
        DX11.Device.ImmediateContext.InputAssembler.SetVertexBuffers(0, _vertexBufferBinding);
        DX11.Device.ImmediateContext.InputAssembler.SetIndexBuffer(_indexBuffer, SharpDX.DXGI.Format.R32_UInt, 0);

    }

    public void Draw()
    {
        DX11.Device.ImmediateContext.DrawIndexed(_indices.Length, 0, 0);
    }
}
```

---

```
List<Mesh> _meshes = new List<Mesh>();

public void SetupShaders()
{
    vertexShaderByteCode = ShaderBytecode.CompileFromFile("MiniTri.fx", "VS", "vs_4_0", ShaderFlags.None, EffectFlags.None);
    vertexShader = new VertexShader(device, vertexShaderByteCode);
    pixelShaderByteCode = ShaderBytecode.CompileFromFile("MiniTri.fx", "PS", "ps_4_0", ShaderFlags.None, EffectFlags.None);

    ...... etc
}

public Mesh SetupMesh(object objectToDraw)
{
    switch(.....)
    {
        // .. implement your beautiful switch ;-)
    }
    return new Mesh(vertices, indices);
}

public void Init()
{
    SetupShaders();

    _meshes.Add(SetupMesh(new Dreieck(.....)));
    _meshes.Add(SetupMesh(new Viereck(.....)));
    _meshes.Add(SetupMesh(new Kreis(.....)));
}


public override void RenderScene(DrawEventArgs args)
{
    Renderer.Device.ImmediateContext.ClearRenderTargetView(Renderer.RenderTargetView, new Color4(0.6f, 0, 0, 0));

    foreach(var mesh in _meshes)
    {
        mesh.SelectBuffers();
        mesh.Draw();
    }
    return;
}
```

Something like that...